# Devise / Rails 4 Mobile authentication failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, devise, nokia, lumia

Im using devise with a rails 4 application.

Authentication works fine on most devices, including some old feature phones.

I am however running into problems with the Nokia Lumia and Blackberry Z10

Please see log snippet below. By the looks of things this appears to be a rails issue rather than a devise problem.

Please Help!

> 014-05-30T09:47:38.668478+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 197.111.223.249 at 2014-05-30 09:47:38 +0000
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.668505+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 197.111.223.249 at 2014-05-30 09:47:38 +0000
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.672961+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.672968+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.674163+00:00 app[web.1]: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.673021+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ckyw9vAfxbgksugLMainfWoG2jRdq7GB5xBBGxqYhCs=", "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.673027+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ckyw9vAfxbgksugLMainfWoG2jRdq7GB5xBBGxqYhCs=", "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.674170+00:00 app[web.1]: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.677792+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 5ms
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.677799+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 5ms
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.683294+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.683299+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:170:in `handle_unverified_request'
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.683289+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.683298+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:163:in`handle_unverified_request'
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.683303+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:177:in `verify_authenticity_token'
>   2014-05-30T09:47:38.683305+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:417:in`_run__3672081613755604432__process_action__callbacks'

Form :

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => "form-signin"}) do |f| %>


<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign in</h2>

  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

 <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
 <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :class=> "form-control" %></div>

 <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
 <%= f.password_field :password , :class=> "form-control"%></div>

 <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
   <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me, :class=> "form-control"%> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
 <% end -%>

<div><%= f.submit "Sign in" ,:class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"%></div>

<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>"/>

 <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
<% end %>
```

HTML in browser

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"beacon-6.newrelic.com","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"007e4afc34","applicationID":"3726760","transactionName":"egsMQRdZXAoARBwAUU8NEVBKRVUVFl9cCkcWCgdC","queueTime":9,"applicationTime":8,"ttGuid":"","agentToken":null,"agent":"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-411.min.js"}</script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,n,e){function r(e){if(!n[e]){var o=n[e]={exports:{}};t[e][0].call(o.exports,function(n){var o=t[e][1][n];return r(o?o:n)},o,o.exports)}return n[e].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o<e.length;o++)r(e[o]);return r}({D5DuLP:[function(t,n){function e(t,n){var e=r[t];return e?e.apply(this,n):(o[t]||(o[t]=[]),void o[t].push(n))}var r={},o={};n.exports=e,e.queues=o,e.handlers=r},{}],handle:[function(t,n){n.exports=t("D5DuLP")},{}],G9z0Bl:[function(t,n){function e(){var t=l.info=NREUM.info;if(t&&t.agent&&t.licenseKey&&t.applicationID&&p&&p.body){l.proto="https"===f.split(":")[0]||t.sslForHttp?"https://":"http://",i("mark",["onload",a()]);var n=p.createElement("script");n.src=l.proto+t.agent,p.body.appendChild(n)}}function r(){"complete"===p.readyState&&o()}function o(){i("mark",["domContent",a()])}function a(){return(new Date).getTime()}var i=t("handle"),u=window,p=u.document,s="addEventListener",c="attachEvent",f=(""+location).split("?")[0],l=n.exports={offset:a(),origin:f,features:[]};p[s]?(p[s]("DOMContentLoaded",o,!1),u[s]("load",e,!1)):(p[c]("onreadystatechange",r),u[c]("onload",e)),i("mark",["firstbyte",a()])},{handle:"D5DuLP"}],loader:[function(t,n){n.exports=t("G9z0Bl")},{}]},{},["G9z0Bl"]);</script>
  <title>Appraiser Events</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application-d90aa6b607e1084c9802752503a4569f.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application-63257f1821daa59804517c178ec3a2be.js"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="eV2KxHpxUoVW9QS8FWt6IaP8SJXoHoJPtYycJPUmVbU=" name="csrf-token" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <p class="notice"></p>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/sign_in" class="form-signin" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="eV2KxHpxUoVW9QS8FWt6IaP8SJXoHoJPtYycJPUmVbU=" /></div>

    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign in</h2>



  <div><label for="user_email">Email</label><br />
  <input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="email" value="" /></div>

  <div><label for="user_password">Password</label><br />
  <input class="form-control" id="user_password" name="user[password]" type="password" /></div>

    <div><input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input class="form-control" id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> <label for="user_remember_me">Remember me</label></div>

  <div><input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" /></div>

  <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="eV2KxHpxUoVW9QS8FWt6IaP8SJXoHoJPtYycJPUmVbU="/>



  <a href="/users/password/new">Forgot your password?</a><br />




</form>


        </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: What browser and version is on the device?  Does it support the hidden field support required by authenticity_token?

Comment: Not sure - this is a relatively new Nokia lumina ? The old feature phones are even fine...

Answer (score 1):

Could you please share your form? It seems to be an issue with the authenticity token.

You can try to add the token in the form options:

```
<%= form_tag ..., authenticity_token: true do %>
```

In your case:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), authenticity_token: true, :html => {:class => "form-signin"}) do |f| %>
```

Comment: I have recently added the hidden input, awaiting to see if that works... 

I could try the authenticity_token on the form as well. 

Strange thing is this works on many other devices.

Thanks!

Comment: ok, adding 
   <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>"/> , 

did not seem to help ? would putting it on the form help ?

Comment: Just to confirm we are talking about authenticity_token: true now ?

Comment: Yes, like I posted in my answer ;-)

Comment: thanks - I have made the change waiting for the device to test!

Comment: Please post the controller action and the HTML that gets rendered in the Browser!

Comment: Ok - will do, but the controller is the standard devise controller

Comment: html added to the post

Comment: Ok, the authenticity token gets rendered... Do you want to submit with AJAX or just normal HTML?

Comment: Normal HTML - this is a standard devise setup